# GFCI outlet and roof leak

Tags: wiring, gfci, leak, roof

The GFCI outlet in one of the bathrooms tripped and is now blinking red. It says it’s now a bad outlet. I’ve flipped the breaker to off for safety but my concern is that this is from a leaky roof I have that might have tripped it. I have friends coming to help me with the roof but is this potentially a rewiring situation or, once the roof is patched and given time to dry, will the wires be okay and I can replace just the GFCI?

Terrified that I will have to rewire 1/5 of my house because of a roof leak that’s been “repaired” twice by “professionals.”

Answer (score 3):

Rewiring should not be necessary.  Just let the existing wires dry.

> 

The hot and neutral are well-insulated individually, in addition to the outer sheath.  It's not likely that the actual copper wire inside the insulation ever got wet, except for the bare ground wire.  Electricity produces a small amount of heat as it travels through the wire.  That little bit of heat will speed up the evaporation process if any moisture exists when you restore  power and start using the outlet again.

> 

If your house was built before the mid to late 1990's, and it still has the original GFCI outlets installed, it's a good idea to replace them with a newer product.  The new GFCI outlets offer better protection than they did 40 years ago.
Just be sure the new outlet is properly installed and the connections to the device are tight and you'll be good to go.

Unrelated but remember:  Smoke detectors save lives.

Comment: Thank you! I’d already gone through and replaced the GFCI outlets in my 1986 built house and just checked all my smoke detectors! Here’s hoping it’s a quick and easy fix! Thank you!